# Error installing Jupyter-Notebook on Window with python 3.9

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
 Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\low_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_ffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_legacy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_password_hasher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\blake2
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iextras\libargon2\src\..\include -Iextras\libargon2\src\blake2 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /Tcextras\libargon2\src\argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\argon2.obj
  argon2.c
  extras\libargon2\src\argon2.c(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Getting this error when trying to install Jupyter-Notebook using pip install

I am using Python 3.9 and pip 20.2.3. I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable - 14.27.29112

Need help to get this resolved.

Comment: If your goal is just to get Jupyter Notebook up and running, I would suggest the the [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) python distribution which has these packages already built.

Comment: Yes, I switched to Anaconda

Comment: I'm assuming you got it fixed with with the Anaconda install @Pratick

Comment: Yes @chip, Anaconda worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I installed reinstalled visual c 2019 build tools via the installer from ms and then I upgraded pip using

```
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

after that it works. I am on python 3.7 installed via chocolatey

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
python -m pip install jupyter notebook
```

Comment: try adding some explanation as to what your answer does to help people understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on my Experience I think Python 3.9 isn't supported yet for Jupyter, So what I did is I install the older version which is the Python 3.8.